# Calculate number of orders in each category per vendor

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my code

```
SELECT Vendor_ID, COUNT(*) AS no_orders, category_name
FROM orders
GROUP BY Vendor_ID, category_name
```

My question is, is there any other better way for this query?

Comment: What's wrong with the current query?  It's about as straight forward as they come.  Define "better" ?

Comment: no, why are you looking for a "better" way? also you have to provide sample data and desired output and explain what are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think this method is good if it works well without problems or slow performance
Just prefer that the category column be a foreign key and use category_id
There must be indexes on the grouping columns to avoid any slow query if the number of records is too large